# What do T, RF and Lost mean in a circuit diagram?

Tags: thermostat, boiler

I recently bought a mechanical thermostat to control the house's temperature during the winter. I need to connect it to the house boiler and into the thermostat, so that the device can get power from the boiler and switch the heating on and off, depending on the temperature of the house.

The device has this circuit diagram included:

[image: Circuit diagram]

First of all, I don't understand what *Lost*, **RF** and **T** are supposed to mean, I've never seen it and I don't think it's standard notation.

Besides, the diagram has the cables **L** (brown in standard color code) and **N** (blue) from which it gets the power, because it has no batteries. Other thermostats I've seen online have then two additional cables to open/close the circuit to control the boiler, but this isn't the case. Shouldn't it be an additional cable to ground the device (yellow and green) as well?

How is this supposed to be assembled?

Complete user manual can be found [here](https://www.cadena88.com/sites/default/files/content/products/files/9310r299/202003111429156681570.pdf) in Spanish and Portuguese.

Answer (score 5):

The left part of the circuit diagram tells you how to connect the device, the right part tells you its internals. You need only to understand the left part in order to install it; the right part can be useful if you need to troubleshoot a problem.
You should connect the hot (live) wire to the terminal marked 1 in the device, and the neutral wire to terminal 2. Terminal 3 is for the thing (a room heater?) you want to control with it: you need to connect one wire of that thing to terminal 3, and the other one to the neutral.

That controlled thing is called "Load" by English speaking electricians, I believe Spanish call it "Lastre" and Portugese "Lastro", literally "ballast" in English. So I think the "Lost" in the diagram is really "Last", unreadable because the diagram is poorly rendered.

In the top right of the diagram is the switch, it has an arrow across it to indicate it is controlled by something, and that something is the box "T": T stands for "temperature" here. The box "RF" is the heating element that is almost always present in thermostats like this. Its function is to turn the heater off a little before the desired room temperature is reached. That is necessary because a significant amount of time will pass before the heat is evenly distributed across the room. If the heating element was omitted, that would result in a room temperature periodically getting too high. The "R" probably is an abbreviation for English "resistor" and Spanish/Portugese "resistencia". The "F" in "RF" could be "fuego", "fire" but I'm far from sure.

Comment: The T in this case is open on rise thermostat. Some stats use Bi-metallic springs so when it heats the contacts open a very cheap and repeatable method although not precise compared to other methods.